# Is there a Javadoc equivalent for Django?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin

I'm hoping to be able to comment code as I go and then have the Documentation generator produce something similar to a Javadoc hopefully sorted by type (views vs model etc).

Comment: python itself uses [sphinx](http://sphinx-doc.org/) for its documentation. there are several other options.

Comment: @hiroprotagonist I was thinking about sphnix but I was sure how appropriate it would be for a web project. It seemed oriented toward python modules. Would the admin-docs work, they would obviously be oriented toward a web project.

Answer (score 2):

Sphinx is good for end-user documentation. However, there's a full PEP standard for docstrings as well. Here's an old but good article on the beauty of inline documentation that's standard in Python:

http://www.electricmonk.nl/log/2008/06/22/why-python-rocks-i-inline-documentation/

Docstrings can go a long way for your development and systems teams, but be sure to check out Sphinx (and https://readthedocs.org) for more. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for api django documentation, we use [django REST swagger](https://github.com/marcgibbons/django-rest-swagger/) where I work, it does its best to generate swagger documentation for as much of your api and models as it can. It will also read formatted comments to better the documentation. Django REST swagger is designed for the rest framework, so it would probably only work for you if you're using [django-rest-framework](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/).